# Search form with arabic letters

Tags: javascript, php, html, autocomplete, arabic

I have an autocomplete search form with cities name and I want to make it compatible with arabic letters(arabic keyboard).Is there a way to interpret the letters as latin letters in the moment they are writen or is there any other way to do this?
An example of that is on google,if I put my keyboard on ARABIC and type london(مخىيخى) the autocomplete from google shows london.

Comment: what language your cities written in?

Answer (score 0):

you can build two arrays containing Arabic and English letters matching with keyboard layouts.

for Example:
var arabic = ["ا", "ل", "ب"];
var english = ["h", "g", "f"]

then you can test onkeydown the pressed letter if it is English or not English.
If English just pass it, if not return the matched letter from array.

Comment: but we can be sure that  the keyboard layouts are the same?

Comment: no you cant make sure, different keyboards apps may have different layouts, and you can't detect keyboard layout via javascript.